# Ansible: How to use 'yum' command with 'expect' module?

Tags: shell, ansible

Here is the playbook:

```yaml
- name: Find "N-1" unpatching ID from the Yum History
  become: yes
  shell: yum history | head -n -3 | tail -n +5 | awk '{print $1}' | head -n +1
  register: unpatch
        
- name: Use expect module to unpatch the server to N-1 level
  expect:
    command: yum history undo {{ unpatch.stdout_lines }}
    responses: 
       'Is this ok \[y/d/N]\:"y"'
```

The error while running this playbook on the 2nd task is as follows:

```json
fatal: [linux-Server-x86-64]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "argument responses is of type <type 'str'> and we were unable to convert to dict: dictionary requested, could not parse JSON or key=value"}
```

I tried to put up various responses to the command `yum history undo ${ID}`, but it either stuck up at the task level in the play or the yum process kept hanging in the system.

```yaml
- name: Use expect module to unpatch the server to N-1 level
  expect:
    command: yum history undo {{ unpatch.stdout_lines }}
    responses: yes
```

Comment: => responsed is a dict (key/value paris) where the key is a regexp to match question against and the value the response to input to the script => `'Is this ok \[y/d/N\]': 'y'` See the [`expect` module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/expect_module.html) as well as [learn yaml in y minutes](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/)

Comment: Your question is "How to answer the question asked by the `yum` command with yes?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already using the `command` module and like to answer the question asked by the `yum` command with `yes` in any case, according `man yum` you could just use `--assumeyes` then

```shell
-y, --assumeyes
              Assume yes; assume that the answer to any question which would be asked is yes.
              Configuration Option: assumeyes
```

and the task would have no need for the `expect` module.

```yaml
- name: Unpatch the server to N-1 level
  command: yum --assumeyes history undo {{ unpatch.stdout_lines }}
```

**Similar Q&A**

- [How to `yum install` always answering `yes` in the y/n questions?](https://superuser.com/a/1340316/754490)
- [How do you answer `yes` for `yum install` automatically?](https://serverfault.com/questions/)

**Further Readings**

- [What is the point of the `yes` command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47344/)
- Or search about `echo yes | <command>`

Comment: - name: Unpatch the server to N-1 level
  command: yum --assumeyes history undo {{ unpatch.stdout }} <<--- This Code Worked